# Does ASP.NET MVC form post autopopulate fields?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have a form like ...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("create", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "accountform_form" }))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(e => e.ShipFirstName)
    ...
}
```

while testing, I was surprised to see the field retained its value on postback even without me assigning it to the view-model.  Using the debugger, the value for `ShipFirstName` is `null` right at the end of the action when returning the view, so why would it show the value that was in the field?  Have I been unnecessarily assigning posted values to view-model properties all this time?  Or is there something else going on?

**Update:** the action is like so...

```
[HttpPost]
public ViewResult Create(AccountFormModel postModel)
{
    var model = new AccountFormModel(postModel, stuff, stuff);  //I use posted values and paramters to create the actual view model
    return view(model);
}
```

So, I see the `GET` form, enter values, say I enter a field and leave a required field blank, submit, the resulting page has the value I entered in the other field, who's putting it there when in the model it's `null`?

Comment: That's the model binder in action.

Comment: No MVC doesn't auto populate anything, you are telling it to populate the field with your view model by calling TextBoxFor

Comment: but at the last step of the action, `return view(model)` `model.ShipFirstName` is null

Comment: Duplicate of [How does asp.net MVC remember my incorrect values on postback?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581042/how-does-asp-net-mvc-remember-my-incorrect-values-on-postback).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into something similar earlier today (a checkbox was always checked). Have a look at [Changing ViewModel properties in POST action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17680982/changing-viewmodel-properties-in-post-action) and see if this is similar.

Basically calling ModelState.Clear() fixed it for me.

Answer (score 2):

As you're passing the model back to the view after it has been POSTed, MVC is taking the stance that you're doing so because the form contains errors.  So, rather than making the user fill out the form again, it repopulates it using the `ModelState` collection.  In this case, the values in the `ModelState` collection take precedence over the changes you make in the action (which does feel a bit weird).

You can get around this either by calling [ModelState.Clear()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.modelstatedictionary.clear%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) or using [ModelState.Remove(string key)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470162%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), where `key` is the name of the property.

If you'd like a full explanation of why this is the case, see [ASP.NET MVC’s Html Helpers Render the Wrong Value!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/simonince/archive/2010/05/05/asp-net-mvc-s-html-helpers-render-the-wrong-value.aspx).  Excerpt:

> ### Why?
>
> ASP.NET MVC assumes that if you’re rendering a View in response to an HTTP POST, and you’re using the Html Helpers, then you are most likely to be redisplaying a form that has failed validation. Therefore, the Html Helpers actually check in ModelState for the value to display in a field before they look in the Model. This enables them to redisplay erroneous data that was entered by the user, and a matching error message if needed.

Comment: @CodeCaster I don't mind the idea so much itself.  The real problem is there is absolutely no mention of it in the official MVC tutorials.  If it was mentioned there to begin with, people would have a better understanding of what's going on.  Plus, it would give us an easy link to find and add to questions like this.

Comment: Have a fresh upvote, five years later. Just spent half a day trying to debug inexplicable misbehaviour before I found this.